# PPA Shows Up Under "All Software" That Is No Longer Enabled

Tags: firefox, software-center, ppa

I used to use the Aurora builds of Firefox, but now I've uninstalled Firefox and gone back to Chromium. I've removed the PPA, but it still shows up under "All Software" in the Ubuntu Software Center, when I click on the arrow to the side of it to display my PPAs. I've checked the Software Sources to see if there's anything leftover, and there's nothing. I use Y PPA Manager, and there's nothing there to remove as well. How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by reinstalling Ubuntu Software Center. :D

Answer (score 0):

I'd check that it doesn't show up in your apt sources list in /etc/apt/, then run an apt-get update from a terminal and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Aha, found something there, the leftovers for two sources. Should I just delete them as they've been removed from my Software Sources?

Comment: Yeah, that should be fine.  You may want to ensure you don't have software from those PPAs still installed, but otherwise go ahead and remove them, then run an apt-get update and it should sort you out.

Comment: It seems like I've run into a little problem. I can't delete any of the files in the folder. I press the delete button and nothing happens, and the delete option in the right click menu is greyed out. How to fix this? :P

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Had to run Nautilus with the gksudo command. And I went into the apt/etc folder, then went into the sources folder and deleted the file corresponding to the Aurora builds, and then ran sudo apt-get update. Went back into the Software Center and nothing had changed. Now what? :S

Comment: Tried another thing, since the last bunch of ideas haven't worked. I readded the same PPA using Y PPA Manager, and then removed it. Also did no good. Argh, why does Software Center have to be so frustrating...

Comment: Did you check in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* ? maybe the ppa is still lurking in one of those files.

Comment: @kyleN Yes, I checked there, and the Aurora files were there, and I deleted them, but they didn't do anything. When I deleted the files for another left over though, that got rid of it on Software Center, but not for Aurora.

Comment: Do you have any software the Aurora PPA still installed?  I wonder if it will continue showing up in Software Center if you do.

Comment: Nope, I have nothing in the Aurora PPA still installed.